# Multiple Post-forms on one page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a User-settings page with 3 Tabs. (url/settings)
If you select a tab it sets its class to "tab_selected" and gets visible.
On the first tab there's a ChangePassword form with a submit button and in my routes file I handle this post request like that:

```
app.get('/settings', function(req, res) {
    res.render(
 //render settingspage
   ); 
});

app.post('/settings', function(req, res) {
    //handle password change
    //render settingspage with e.g. "password set" message
});
```

On my second tab, I now implemented a form to change and submit Userrights.
Means I've got a second post-request with app.post('/settings').
Right now, my second form points to app.post('url/userrights') which also renders /settings again.
This feels like I'm doing it wrong. It's the same page but a different url after submitting.

Is there any way to handle multiple Post-forms on one page correctly?

Comment: I don't know enough about node.js, but you could go for an ajax solution and handle submission of each form through ajax requests, and update the page accordingly with the results

Comment: Do you have a good website/tutorial or sth. where it's explained how this is done?

Comment: Not really, that is how I would have done it with jquery or angular, so mentioned it.

Comment: Thanks a lot though.